# SQLSTATE[HY093] Error

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to run the following in PHP:

```
$stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=:email");
$stmt->execute(array(":email"=>$user_email));
$count = $stmt->rowCount();

if($count==0){

$stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,email,password,ip)VALUES(:uname, :email, :password, :ip)");
$stmt->bindParam(":username",$username);
$stmt->bindParam(":email",$useremail);
 $stmt->bindParam(":password",$hasheduserpassword);
$stmt->bindParam(":ip",$userip);
```

As a result, I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

In the query you are defining uname while setting a parameter called username
try

```
$stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,email,password,ip)VALUES(:username, :email, :password, :ip)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `error` lies here

```
  $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,email,password,ip)VALUES(:uname, :email, :password, :ip)");
 //   $stmt->bindParam(":username",$username);// this shoud be uname
 $stmt->bindParam(":uname",$username);
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is here:

`VALUES(:uname,`

`$stmt->bindParam(":username",$username);`

MySql is looking for `:username` but it cannot find it because you named it `:uname`.

Both must match.